# SonarQube does not start in Linux (localhost)

Tags: jvm, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I am trying to install and configure sonarqube to use it in small poroyect in my machine (Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS)  y have already download the zip Sonarqube 7.7 community edition from the oficial web and unzipped in /opt/. I tryed to do as is say in the guide from sonar and execute `./sonar.sh console`  in the path `/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64` and I get problems with the log permisions .

```
Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | ERROR: Could not write pid file /opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/./SonarQube.pid: Permission denied
Unable to open logfile ../../logs/sonar.log: Permission denied
```

So I try the same as superuser and I get

```
Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    | 
jvm 1    | 2019.04.05 19:55:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
jvm 1    | 2019.04.05 19:55:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
jvm 1    | 2019.04.05 19:55:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
jvm 1    | 2019.04.05 19:55:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
jvm 1    | 2019.04.05 19:55:48 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
jvm 1    | 2019.04.05 19:55:48 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
jvm 1    | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
jvm 1    | 2019.04.05 19:55:51 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
jvm 1    | 2019.04.05 19:55:51 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2019.04.05 19:55:51 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
jvm 1    | 2019.04.05 19:55:51 INFO  app[][o.e.c.t.TransportClientNodesService] failed to get node info for {#transport#-1}{pr4ED0vsRgCYZjgn1jbLlQ}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9001}, disconnecting...
jvm 1    | java.lang.IllegalStateException: Future got interrupted
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.get(FutureUtils.java:60)
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.action.support.AdapterActionFuture.actionGet(AdapterActionFuture.java:34)
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectionManager.internalOpenConnection(ConnectionManager.java:226)
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:85)
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.openConnection(TransportService.java:367)
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler.doSample(TransportClientNodesService.java:410)
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$NodeSampler.sample(TransportClientNodesService.java:361)
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.addTransportAddresses(TransportClientNodesService.java:202)
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.addTransportAddress(TransportClient.java:342)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.application.es.EsConnectorImpl$MinimalTransportClient.<init>(EsConnectorImpl.java:108)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.application.es.EsConnectorImpl.buildTransportClient(EsConnectorImpl.java:89)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.application.es.EsConnectorImpl.getTransportClient(EsConnectorImpl.java:74)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.application.es.EsConnectorImpl.getClusterHealthStatus(EsConnectorImpl.java:61)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.application.process.EsProcessMonitor.checkStatus(EsProcessMonitor.java:90)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.application.process.EsProcessMonitor.checkOperational(EsProcessMonitor.java:75)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.application.process.EsProcessMonitor.isOperational(EsProcessMonitor.java:60)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.application.process.SQProcess.refreshState(SQProcess.java:161)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.application.process.SQProcess$EventWatcher.run(SQProcess.java:220)
jvm 1    | Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: null
jvm 1    |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1038)
jvm 1    |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1343)
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture$Sync.get(BaseFuture.java:251)
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture.get(BaseFuture.java:94)
jvm 1    |  at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.get(FutureUtils.java:57)
jvm 1    |  ... 17 common frames omitted
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I do not understand the error I get and why it does not start the sonarqube.

Comment: Don't try to use superuser. Just change the access rights on the complete SonarQube folder for the user you use.

Comment: Thanks it is the next thing I tried and it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't try to use superuser. Just change the access rights on the complete SonarQube folder for the user you use.

Comment: This worked for me like magic. Thank you.
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/sonarqube

Answer (score 0):

[to resolve this ./SonarQube pid permission denied
chack $vi /etc/sudoers  file user added or not
sonar ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3m0i.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Code should be pasted as text, and formatted using Markdown. (The toolbar in the Stack Overflow editor can help you with this.) Code within images is harder to read, less accessible, can't be copied, and doesn't show up in relevant searches. Please [edit] your post to include the code as text; this will help you get better responses, and help prevent your answer from getting deleted.